# Prove that $\prod_{k=2}^{99}\frac{k^{3}-1}{k^{3}+1}$ is greater than $\frac{2}{3}$.

Tags: inequality, products

I have to prove that the product
$$\prod_{k=2}^{99}\frac{k^{3}-1}{k^{3}+1}$$
is greater than $\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}$.

I've tried to write $k^{3}-1$ as $(k-1)(k^{2}+k+1)$ or another ways but I couldn't finish it.

Comment: You have factored the numerator. The denominator likewise factors as $(k+1)(k^2-k+1)$.

Comment: The infinite variation appears as problem 5.3.7.(b) in Larson's Problem Solving Through Problems, though the author of the book makes the mistake of starting the index at $1$ instead of $2,$ which would make the product $0$. https://www.amazon.com/Problem-Solving-Through-Problems-Problem-Mathematics/dp/0387961712/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
f(n)
&=\prod_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{k^{3}-1}{k^{3}+1}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=2}^{n}(k^{3}-1)}{\prod_{k=2}^{n}(k^{3}+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=2}^{n}(k-1)(k^2+k+1)}{\prod_{k=2}^{n}(k+1)(k^2-k+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}k}{\prod_{k=3}^{n+1}k}\dfrac{\prod_{k=3}^{n+1}((k-1)^2+(k-1)+1)}{\prod_{k=2}^{n}(k^2-k+1)}
\qquad\text{(this is the only clever step)}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{n(n+1)}\dfrac{\prod_{k=3}^{n+1}(k^2-2k+1+k-1+1)}{\prod_{k=2}^{n}(k^2-k+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{n(n+1)}\dfrac{\prod_{k=3}^{n+1}(k^2-k+1)}{\prod_{k=2}^{n}(k^2-k+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{n(n+1)}\dfrac{(n+1)^2-(n+1)+1)}{2^2-2+1}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{n(n+1)}\dfrac{n^2+2n+1-n-1+1}{3}\\
&=\dfrac23\dfrac{n^2+n+1}{n^2+n}\\
&=\dfrac23(1+\dfrac1{n^2+n})\\
&\gt \dfrac23
\qquad\text{for all } n\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 3):

Use : $k^2 - k + 1 = (k-1)^2 + (k-1) + 1$ to cancel out some more terms.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$k^3+1=(k+1)(k^2-k+1)$$

**Hint 2:**

$$(k+1)^2-(k+1)+1=k^2+k+1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} \prod_{k=2}^{99} \frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1} 
&= \prod_{k=2}^{99} \frac{(k-1)(k^2+k+1)}{(k+1)(k^2-k+1)} \\
&= \Biggl(\prod_{k=2}^{99} \frac{k^2+k+1}{k+1}\Biggl) \Biggl(\prod_{k=2}^{99} \frac{k-1}{k^2-k+1} \Biggl) \space \space \text{(Separability of Multiple Products)} \\
&= \frac{\prod_{k=2}^{99} \frac{k^2+k+1}{k+1}}{\prod_{k=2}^{99} \frac{k^2-k+1}{k-1}} \\
&= \frac{\prod_{k=2}^{99} \frac{(k+1)^2-(k+1)+1}{k+1}}{\prod_{k=2}^{99} \frac{(k-1)^2+(k-1)+1}{k-1}} \\
&= \frac{\prod_{k=2}^{99} (k+1)-1+\frac{1}{k+1}}{\prod_{k=2}^{99} (k-1)+1+\frac{1}{k-1}} \\
&= \frac{\prod_{n=3}^{100} n-1+\frac{1}{n}}{\prod_{n=1}^{98} n+1+\frac{1}{n}} \\
&= \Biggl(\prod_{k=3}^{98} \frac{(n+\frac{1}{n})-1}{(n+\frac{1}{n})+1}\Biggl) \Biggl(\frac{\prod_{n=99}^{100} n+\frac{1}{n}-1}{\prod_{k=1}^{2} n+\frac{1}{n}+1}\Biggl) \\
&= \Biggl(\prod_{k=3}^{98} 1-\frac{2}{n+1+\frac{1}{n}}\Biggl) \Biggl(\frac{\prod_{n=99}^{100} n+\frac{1}{n}-1}{\prod_{k=1}^{2} n+\frac{1}{n}+1}\Biggl) \\ \end{align}$$
At this stage, we can make a numeric calculation:

$$\Biggl(\prod_{k=3}^{98} 1-\frac{2}{n+1+\frac{1}{n}}\Biggl)=\frac{7}{13} \cdot \frac{13}{21} \cdot \frac{21}{31} \cdots \frac{98 \cdot 99+1-2\cdot 98}{98 \cdot 99+1}=\frac{7}{98 \cdot 99 +1}$$
$$\Biggl(\frac{\prod_{n=99}^{100} n+\frac{1}{n}-1}{\prod_{k=1}^{2} n+\frac{1}{n}+1}\Biggl)=\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{(98 \cdot 99+1)\cdot(99 \cdot 100+1)}{7 \cdot 99 \cdot 100}$$

The resultant product is: $$\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{(98\cdot 99+1) \cdot (99 \cdot 100+1)}{7 \cdot 99 \cdot 100} \cdot \frac{7}{98 \cdot 99+1}=\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{9901}{9900} \gt \frac{2}{3}$$